# VIM: Having a macro jump to a certain position

Tags: vim

So let's say my current macro is:

```
map! \aa aabbccdd
```

and I want it so that whenever the command executes, the text will be printed and the cursor will be at a certain character (let's say the first occurrence of b). What do I need so that my macro will move my cursor to the first occurrence of b whenever it's used?

Comment: It's not very clear what you're asking. It would be better if you provided a real example with a before and after. As it stands, your mapping would append `abbccdd` to the buffer (the first `a` counts as an append and puts you into insert mode). Is this what you're trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

If I understood your question correctly, you wish your macro to insert `aabbccdd` and move the cursor to the first `b`. This is one way to do it:

```
map \aa mziaabbccdd<Esc>`zfb
```

Of course, finding the first `b` is not really all that useful, and might not translate well to your real problem.

Answer (score 1):

A *macro* is just a recording of commands and entered text. Therefore, any motions you'd "normally" use to position the cursor are captured in there, too.

So, in your example, you can jump to the beginning of your entered text with `` `[ ``, and then move on to the first `b` with `fb`. Append those two motions to the end of your macro recording, and you're done!